# How to re apply js and css files for appended tags by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create infinite pagination. I am sending an id of a last element using ajax to a controller. Then, the controller is returning response consisted of html tags.

When I am trying to append it into a div, javascript and css files doesn't apply for new-added html tags. I have scanned some questions on the website, but I couldn't find any solution for my problem.
Could you help?

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var counting = 1;
    $(document).on('click', '.pagination-button', function() {
      var id = $('.projects:last').data('id');
      $.ajax({
        url: '/projects/projectloader/',
        type: "post",
        beforeSend: function() {
          if (counting > 0)
            $('.ajax-load').show();
          $('.mobile-product-loader').hide();
        },
        data: {
          id: id,
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data) {
            $('.ajax-load').hide();
            $(".cbp-wrapper").append(data);
            $('.mobile-product-loader').show();
            counting++;
            console.log(data);
          } else if (!data) {
            $('.ajax-load').hide();
            $('.mobile-product-loader').hide();
            console.log('no data');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: CSS is automatically applied to appended DOM.

Comment: Then, what about javascript files?

Comment: You cannot "apply a javascript file". You have to call the methods you need to call on the newly added DOM nodes.

Comment: What javascript are you trying to apply?

Comment: cube.portfolio.js plug in

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try something like this :

```
    function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
    if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js") //dynamically load and add this .js file
loadjscssfile("javascript.php", "js") //dynamically load "javascript.php" as a JavaScript file
loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css") ////dynamically load and add this .css file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to apply events to dynamic generated content, consider to refactor your event syntax (in main js files) with event delegation, for example:

```
$(document).on("click", '.mylink', function(event) { 
    alert("new link clicked!");
});
```

Imho its best option to support events in dynamic generated content.